# how can i get value from inside of function?

Tags: php, echo

Is it possible to get those values inside of function and use those outside of function
here is my code:

```
   <?
    function expenditure () {
    $totalexpenditure = $sum1 + $sum2;
    }
    function income () {
    totalincome = $sum1 + $sum2;
    }
    $profit = $totalincome - $totalexpenditure;
   ?>
```

now my question is how can  i get value of totalincome and toatalexpenditure ?
i am learning php alos new in php so please help me guys.

Comment: I must be missing something, why don't you just return totalincome and totalexpenditure from the functions?

Comment: Do you know that with your functions: 1) you will have `$profit` equal to zero, unless 2) not assigning values to `$sum1` and `$sum2`, and not making them `global` will create another problem?

Comment: please can you pick the second answer as the answer?

Answer (score 10):

```
<?
function expenditure ($sum1, $sum2) {
    $totalexpenditure = $sum1 + $sum2;
    return $totalexpenditure;
}

function income ($sum1, $sum2) {
    $totalincome = $sum1 + $sum2;
    return $totalincome;
}

$profit = income ($sum1, $sum2) - expenditure($sum1, $sum2) ;
?>
```

[return statement](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php)

Comment: No, it is incorrect - the `$sum1` and `$sum2` are not defined.

Comment: But that was not the question, he have problems with the usage of return statement. In his example the last line is an equation so, I think he don't have problems with it, and it is not important...

Comment: The question stated: `Is it possible to get those values inside of function and (...)` - so this was the question also about how to pass and use `$sum1` and `$sum2` inside a function.

Comment: Ok mr, you are the king of the php, i don't have time for this.

Comment: @Roki sorry, I did not mean to offend you. Why don't you just correct your answer so I can upvote it and visitors are not confused seeing solution that does not work? Deal?

Comment: @Tadeck: I did it before you eat me alive :-)

Comment: @stereofrog You may be right. It may be what OP wanted. In that case you may be right and the code does not need to be fully correct.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is wrong, because:

- the variables within functions do not have value assigned (you should assign it preferably by function parameters, but another - working, but wrong - solution is making them global variables),
- in the example given, `$profit` will be always `0` (zero).

The solutions are three:

***Solution no. 1:***

```
function expenditure ($sum1, $sum2) {
    $expenditure = $sum1 + $sum2;
    return $expenditure;
}

function income ($sum1, $sum2) {
    $income = $sum1 + $sum2;
    return $income;
}
```

And then you can use it like that:

```
$profit = income(10, 200) - expenditure(20,18);
```

***Solution no. 2:***

```
class Finances {
    public $expenditure = 0;
    public $income = 0;
    public function addExpense($expense) {
        $this->expenditure = $this->expenditure + $expense;
        return $this;
    }
    public function addIncome($income) {
        $this->income = $this->income + $income;
        return $this;
    }
    public function getProfit() {
        return $this->income - $this->expenditure;
    }
}
```

and then you can use it like that:

```
$my_finances = new Finances();
$my_finances->addExpense(20)->addExpense(18)->addIncome(10)->addIncome(10);
$profit = $my_finances->getProfit();
```

***Solution no. 3:* (avoid using!)**

```
function expenditure() {
    global $sum1, $sum2;
    return $sum1 + $sum2;
}
function income() {
    global $sum1, $sum2;
    return $sum1 + $sum2;
}
```

And then you use it like that:

```
$sum1 = 10;
$sum2 = 200;
$expenditure = expenditure();
$sum1 = 20;
$sum2 = 30;
$income = income();
$profit = $income - $expenditure;
```

I hope you see, why the *Solution no. 3* is such a bad idea (as generally using `global` variables to pass something to function is bad idea).

Comment: hey thanks for u answer but i want to get a value of 1 veriables please see my full code

Comment: @hamp please describe it in a lot more details, preferably using examples. For now I do not know why the solution does not suit you and what variable do you need. If you are saying about `$profit` variable, then both proper solutions mentioned (1st and 2nd) should be ok for you. Please give more details.

Comment: What errors did you encounter? Can you give us all more details about what is the result of the code? And first of all - do what others say about `return` statement. Your code should return `$total` from the function and then you should tell us what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This relates to another problem, that you may face at a later stage. What if you wanted to pass 2 variables in a function and change both their values.

```
$var1 = 22;
$var2 = 15;

function multi2(&$x, &$y){
    $x = $x * 2;
    $y = $y * 2;
}

multi2($var1, $var2);
print $var1 . ", " . $var2;
```

You will get this as an output

```
44, 30
```

The `$x` and `$y` parameters are not a variable themselves, but a reference (defined by `&`) to the variables passed through, this is helpful if you require to change the values external variables internally.

Link to understand more http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php